# I want to give alert to user when date is null in database by using php and js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

This is js code. Which will pop up in html code.This isn't working.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        $.get("popup.php", function(data, status){
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

This is php code.

```
<?php

include("admin/pages/connect.php"); 

$link=Connection();
if (!$link)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($link));
    }

    mysqli_select_db($link, "form");

    $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `form` WHERE `Received_Date` IS NULL"); 

    $receivedate = 'Received_Date';


    if($result === true)
    {
        echo "You have item not receive yet.";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "All items are received.";
    }

?>
```

The alert is come up but always echo "You have item not receive yet." even all item are received.

Comment: You should use AJAX properly. Also, your get doesn't pass any parameters to the php script. No idea why you are assigning a string to $receivedate, and your if statement makes no sense. If the query is successful, it won't return true. It will return false if it fails. But no records doesn't necessarily mean failure. Way too many errors to correct. You need to do more testing and research....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the php code to this.

```
<?php

include("admin/pages/connect.php"); 

$link=Connection();
if (!$link)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($link));
    }

    mysqli_select_db($link, "form");

    $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `form` WHERE `Received_Date` IS NULL"); 

    $receivedate = 'Received_Date';


    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        echo "You have item not receive yet.";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "All items are received.";
    }

?>
```

And infact, using the best practices, It is recommended to do the data communication between client and server using json

Hence, in php, you shouldn't simply echo your text. Instead, it should be

```
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
        {
            $msg = "You have item not receive yet.";
        }
        else
        {
            $msg = "All items are received.";
        } 

$response['msg'] = $msg;
echo json_encode($response);
```

And on Jquery side,

```
$.get("popup.php", function(data, status){
            alert("Data: " + data.msg + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
```

Comment: Alright.. Can you please mark this answer as correct @azziananana

Answer (score 2):

```
if($result === true)
```

means the query is error free. It has run successfully, but it does not return any result. You have to compare result in order to get correct popup.

try this,

```
if($result === true)
{
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0) {
       echo "You have item not receive yet.";
    } else {
       echo "All items are received.";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Error In query";
}
```

Comment: its work when remove if($result === true).. thanks a lot for helping ^^)

Comment: @azziananana Anytime ;-)

Answer (score -1):

```
//changed your syntax in query
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM form WHERE Received_Date IS NULL"); 
    //what is the purpose of the next line???
    $receivedate = 'Received_Date';
    //count the result
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    //check if the count bigger then 0
    if($count > '0')
    {
        echo "You have item not receive yet.";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "All items are received.";
    }
```